# Excel search value and pair it with a value from the same row. Search the value from another sheet and print out true if it is there

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a pythoneer and I am struggling hard with Excel code.

The thing is that I should search for value `x` from a column `C`. When `x` is found take another value (`id number`) from the same row where `x` is. Then search `sheet2` for the same value (`id number`) and print out `True` in `sheet2` column `c`.

Any guidance with this would be largely appreciated

Comment: This sounds like a double `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`/`MATCH`. You can find several examples online (this site and otherwise) similar to what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: So your formula will be in the Sheet 2 column C correct (Then I agree with ImaginaryHuman)? Or do you want to put the formula somewhere else and then print it to the sheet 2 column C?

Comment: Sorry for repeating, but double VLOOKUP syntax is totally new. I want to put the formula in the sheet 2 column C so that the once the formula is there it will automatically create a pathway to the sheet1 and check if new x(values) has been inserted and update the boolean statement accordingly. Imaginaryhuman072889, any links to find double VLOOKUPS?

Comment: Your description is very difficult to follow.  Please provide sample data and expected results.  Hard to give you formula suggestions without knowing exact data layout.